# How to transform css code to have support in Safari , Opera and Chrome?

Tags: html, asp.net, css, web

I have this style in CSS for a DIV:

```
background: repeating-linear-gradient(-55deg, #F00, #F00 10px, #F00 10px, #FFF 11px) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent
```

The problem is that the style only works with mozilla and IE , and I need to work with safari, opera and chrome .

Answer (score 1):

From [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeating-linear-gradient#bc3)

> Gecko, Opera & Webkit considers  to start to the right, instead of the top. I.e. it considered an angle of 0deg as a direction indicator pointing to the right. This is different from the latest specification where an angle of 0deg as a direction indicator points to the top.